# Can you use brandy instead of rum in cake recipe

Tags: baking, substitutions, cake, alcohol, rum

Can you use brandy instead of rum in a cake recipe

Comment: Substitution questions should provide a reason for the substitution and, preferably, the specific recipe (or an example of one) that it might be used in. [See our guidelines](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/substitutions/info). Providing details is far better than copy/pasting the title into the question.

Comment: FWIW, *most* spirits in baking recipes are interchangeable because they're only used for flavouring anyway, so it comes down to a question of whether you think brandy tastes similar enough to rum to qualify.

Answer (score 4):

Almost certainly yes, but the flavors will be slightly different.

Brandy is likely to be slightly more acidic than rum, but otherwise quite similar in composition, and should perform in the same way.

If you want a more tailored answer, you should provide more information, such as the full recipe.

See also:  [Are there any general principles of ingredient substitutions?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/35814/are-there-any-general-principles-of-ingredient-substitutions)

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly, "No". Changing rum to brandy makes "Brandy Cake" (a quick search reveals several "Brandy Cake" recipes). In other words, it becomes *something different entirely* (can I replace Tuna for Beef in a steak?)

There is nothing wrong with Brandy Cake, but it isn't 'Rum Cake'.

> From:  [Are there any general principles of ingredient substitutions?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/35814/are-there-any-general-principles-of-ingredient-substitutions)
>
> If a dish is defined by a certain ingredient (such as the rum
>   in rum balls), then substituting for the signature ingredient really
>   isn't practical. You would be creating a new dish, or changing what
>   its core is.

Comment: the OP does not say that it is a 'Rum Cake' recipe.