# Non-coconut substitute for coconut cream?

Tags: substitutions, coconut

I found a recipe for cornbread that I want to try, but it calls for "1 cup Goya coconut cream". Two problems with this: one, I don't have any such creature (I'm not even 100% confident I know what it is), and two, I passionately hate, detest, and abhor the taste of coconut. You won't find me boiling up some grated coconut to make my own coconut cream, which is the only substitution suggestion I've found.

So, given that (as mentioned) I hate, detest, and abhor the taste of coconut, what can I use instead? What role is the coconut cream playing here? The ingredients are:

1 cup of flour
1 cup of sugar
1 cup corn meal
1 dash of salt
1 cup of corn oil
4 tsp baking powder
1 cup Goya coconut cream
4 eggs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing unusual about that recipe *except* the coconut cream and the nearly dessert like sugar level.  Use regular dairy cream instead, which would be more standard anyway.

See also:  [Are there any general principles of ingredient substitutions?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/35814/are-there-any-general-principles-of-ingredient-substitutions)